# How does Java non-fair ReentrantReadWriteLock really work?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written the following test code in Java using ReentrantReadWriteLock to understand the difference between fair and non-fair mode. However, I see in both modes the result and output is always the same. It seems it's always working in fair mode. Can anybody explain in which case fair and non-fair mode will result in different behaviors?

```
package lockTest;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class MyLockTest {
    static private ReadWriteLock myLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(false);

    public class Reader extends Thread {
        int val_;
        public Reader(int val) {
            val_ = val;
        }
        public void run() {
            if (val_ > 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            myLock.readLock().lock();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Reader inside critical section - val: " + val_ + "-----");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public class Writer extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            myLock.writeLock().lock();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Writer inside critical section *****");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyLockTest test1 = new MyLockTest();
        MyLockTest.Reader reader1 = test1.new Reader(0);
        MyLockTest.Writer writer1 = test1.new Writer();
        MyLockTest.Reader reader2 = test1.new Reader(1);

        reader2.start();
        writer1.start();
        reader1.start();
    }
}
```

The output is always:

```
Thread-0: Reader inside critical section - val: 0-----
Thread-1: Writer inside critical section *****
Thread-2: Reader inside critical section - val: 1-----
```

The output above is what I expect to see when I change Lock creation to fair mode:

```
static private ReadWriteLock myLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
```

For non-fair mode I would expect to see the following output:

```
Thread-0: Reader inside critical section - val: 0-----
Thread-2: Reader inside critical section - val: 1-----
Thread-1: Writer inside critical section *****
```

Comment: I am not sure of any specifics, but I think this will depend heavily on the underlying platform. So if you require "fair" behavior, specify it; don't rely on results from testing in one specific environment.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "really work" here. Are you asking for the behavioral differences or implementation details?

Comment: There is no "non-fair" mode. The two modes are "fair" and "default." The fair mode is required by the library API to behave in a certain way, but the API does _not_ require the default mode to behave in any special way.  In particular, it does not require the default mode to be any different from the fair mode.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: I'm not sure what you mean by "There is no 'non-fair' mode." The documentation for `ReentrantReadWriteLock` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) explicitly has a header under "Acquisition order" labelled "Non-fair mode (default)" which starts with "When constructed as non-fair..." Unfairness is a really common term in mutual exclusion which means unspecified acquisition order.

Comment: I guess I said that badly.  Yes, the documentation uses the phrase "non-fair," but there's nothing in the documentation that requires the "non-fair" mode to not be fair. An implementation that simply ignored the `fair` constructor argument and _always_ constructed a fair lock would be perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "fair" versus "non-fair" mode affects how the lock is assigned to threads in case of contention.

From the Javadoc for [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html): using the "non-fair" mode, *the order of entry to the read and write lock is unspecified*, while using the "fair" mode, *threads contend for entry using an approximately arrival-order policy.*

---

We can see how using fair/non-fair affects program execution by having some thread contend over the same lock; see the program below.

Running the sample code, a `ReentrantWriteLock` is contended by different threads; after 1000 lock operations, we dump how many times each thread acquired the lock.

In case `USE_FAIR=false` is used, counts are random, and a possible output is:

```
Thread thread-B finished, count=920
Thread thread-A finished, count=79
Thread thread-D finished, count=0
Thread thread-C finished, count=0
```

in case `USE_FAIR=true` is used, the output is always like

```
Thread thread-D finished, count=249
Thread thread-A finished, count=250
Thread thread-C finished, count=250
Thread thread-B finished, count=250
```

**Sample code**

```
package sample1;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class UseLock {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    UseLock o = new UseLock();
    o.go();
  }

  private void go() {
    TotalPermits tp = new TotalPermits();

    tp.lock.writeLock().lock();

    Contender a = new Contender(tp, "thread-A");
    Contender b = new Contender(tp, "thread-B");
    Contender c = new Contender(tp, "thread-C");
    Contender d = new Contender(tp, "thread-D");

    a.start();
    b.start();
    c.start();
    d.start();

    tp.lock.writeLock().unlock();
  }
}

class TotalPermits {
  private static final boolean USE_FAIR = true;

  private int count = 1_000;
  ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(USE_FAIR);

  public boolean get() {
    try {
      lock.writeLock().lock();
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
      return --count>0;
    } finally {
      lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
  }
}

class Contender extends Thread {
  private int count = 0;
  final String name;
  final TotalPermits tp;

  Contender(TotalPermits tp, String name) {
    this.tp = tp;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while ( tp.get() ) {
      count++;
    }
    System.out.printf("Thread %s finished, count=%d%n", name, count);
  }
}
```

---

**Note:**

The sample code above uses a "write" lock, which can only be held by one thread at a time. So we can use that to divide N permits across the contenders. On the other hand, the "read" lock can be held by multiple threads, as long as none is holding the write lock.

Comment: Thank you. Your response is correct. Something to add is that I was orienting the question to the fairness between write and read locks worried that the writer will be starved by hundreds of readers. However the concept of fairness is wider and refers to a any type of contention writer-writer, writer-reader, reader-reader.